# Find 2 points given length, starting point, and angles between another line with given slope m

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Someone please help a lost damsel in distress.  I have point `(x1,y1)`.  I have the slope of the line labeled `m`.  I need to get the points `(x2,y2)` and `(x3,y3)`.  They're a distance `d = 30` away from `(x1,y1)`.  And there's a `30°` angle between them and the line with slope `m`.  What do I do?

Btw the distance can be anything, and the angle can be anything, for example  `d = 40` and angle is `45°`.  But I'll always be treating `(x1,y1)` as `(0,0)` and I'll always have the slope `m`.  Yes it is the tip of an arrow, so those lines always need to be drawn to create an arrow head.  And the arrow can be pointing in any direction.  I'm not sure what variable I can provide to indicate what direction the arrow is pointing.  For this example, `downward` direction, and `d = 30` and angle is `30°` can be used.  Thank you in advance.  I'm here if any more info is needed.

[image]

Edit:  here's latest working results

[image: directed graph]

here's the bug I was getting, I posted my workaround for it in comments.  Idk how to handle it using the equations but I can share whatever info is needed to figure that out . The lines would switch direction after redrawing the same graph, with same nodes and lines in same place.  There is a variable that changes each redraw, the x and y of the center of each node gets offset by a random value between 1 and 10.  Idk what the issue is but what I have now seems to be working 100% of the time

[image: bug]

Update:  example with several more nodes.  seems to be working flawlessly!

[image: latest result]

Comment: If the distance and angle can be anything, why did you specify that the distance is $30$ and the angle is $30$ degrees with respect to the line with slope $m$? I'd like to clarify whether those figures truly matter to you or not

Comment: umm i chose 30 length and 30 degrees because i think that will draw a nice arrow head.  but i could end up tweaking it to 45 degrees or something so the arrow head would be wider i guess.  i think they can just be treated as a variable d and angle

Comment: I see. Well I'll just run with your numbers. It's a matter of first finding the angle that the slope $m$ line makes with the $x$-axis, which is done using the arctangent function. Call this angle $\theta$. Once done, imagine a circle with radius $30$ centred at $(0,0)$. You want to calculate the points located at a deviation of $30$ degrees in either direction from the original line (pretend that $(x_1,y_1) = (0,0)$ for now), which itself has a deflection of $\theta$ from the $x$-axis; therefore, the angle each new point makes with the $x$-axis is $\theta + 30$ degrees and $\theta - 30$ degree

Comment: (continued) then the coordinates of the new points, via trigonometry, are simply $(30cos(\theta-30), 30sin(\theta -30))$ and $(30cos(\theta + 30), 30sin(\theta + 30))$. To put them in their proper locations, translate all the coordinates by $(x_1, y_1)$

Comment: In summary: given a line with a point $(x_1,y_1)$ with slope $m$, the coordinates of points at a deflection of angles $-a$ and $a$ and distance $d$ from $(x_1, y_1)$ are given by $(x_1+d\cos(\arctan(m)-a), y_1+d\sin(\arctan(m)-a))$ and $(x_1+d\cos(\arctan(m)+a), y_1+d\sin(\arctan(m)+a))$

Comment: wow thx @H.sapiensrex this makes sense.  I'm implementing this in code I can share a pic once its working ^^

Comment: No worries! Do note that this method won't work if your original line is a vertical one, because $m$ in that case is undefined. However, you can simply add a new case for that, where the coordinates of your new points are $(x_1+dcos(\pi/2 -a), y_1+dsin(\pi/2 -a))$ and $(x_1+dcos(\pi/2 +a), y_1+dsin(\pi/2 +a))$ (as you can tell, I'm thinking in terms of radians rather than degrees. I recommend you do the same)

Comment: well I got everything working! xD  ill post a pic on the original post.  I came across an intermittent thing where the arrow head lines went in the opposite direction, not sure why, but I added some code to check what direction the line is pointing, and compare the y value of p2 and p3, to y value of the diametrically opposite points of their circle with the original point as its center, and choose whichever set of points fits the direction the arrow is pointing in.  I'm running out of characters but I can explain more

Comment: Nice! I did think you might run into that issue though. The reason that's happening is due to the periodicity of the arctangent function. To illustrate: suppose you had the points $(a, -b)$ and $(-a, b)$ and drew an arrow from the origin to each of them. You can see that they lie on the same line, hence they have the same $m$ value and thus the angle. In other words, the arctangent cannot distinguish between diametrically opposite arrows/vectors. What you can use instead is called the atan2 function, which was designed to overcome this hurdle. I believe it is a standard part of most

Comment: programming languages. If you go with this option, your new coordinates will be given by $(x_1+d\cos(\atan2(y_1/x_1)-a), y_1 +d\sin(\atan2(y_1/x_1)-a))$ and $(x_1+d\cos(\atan2(y_1/x_1)+a), y_1+d\cos(\atan2(y_1/x_1)+a))$. Give that a go and it should work, and let me know if it doesn't as I'm a bit tired and I may have made a mistake somewhere lol

Comment: @H.sapiensrex i tried atan2, was getting intermittent result where the arrow head was rotated 90 degrees.  i reverted back to previous method, it seems to cover the edge cases.  not sure why atan2 wasn’t giving desired result.  if the equation is correct, it might be a bug in my code, and I wouldn’t want to consume your time bc of that. i tried atan2 with (cos/sin, cos/sin) and (cos/sin, cos/cos) and both were rotated from the desired angle by some degree.  i assumed the double cos in ur above formula was a typo.  is there something i should do to update this question as answered? 

Comment: Great catch! Yes, that was an error on my part; that double cos was indeed a typo (it should have been sin). That's what I get for trying to do maths fatigued, lol. If there are any more mathematical questions you've got, I'm happy to help, but I'm afraid I have no experience coding whatsoever, so I'd be more of a hindrance than a help in debugging  I am happy to hear that at least one method worked though! As for updating it to be answered, you won't be able to currently as none has been actually posted. If I were to make my initial comments into an answer, would you consider accepting it?

Comment: yes ofc!  that's the least I could do .  i had stayed up to 6 am that night too .  i put a pic of an example with more going on.  works like a charm

Comment: Thank you, I will copy paste it as a proper answer after I finish work today :) isn't it funny how that works? You wonder about one little thing and then suddenly your brain goes into overdrive and won't let go until it's solved  in any case, I'm glad you were able to get it working. If you have any future questions please don't hesitate to tag me; I may have zero coding skills and I sure don't know all there is to know about maths, but I'm always happy to help if I can 